Why does the flapper in my toilet tank rest on a raised seat about 4" above the bottom of the tank?
We bought a house with one piece low flow toilets. Today I replaced the water control valve and the flapper in one toilet. I noticed when I  emptied the tank and the water is no longer flowing down the flapper's hole (forgive me for not knowing the correct term), there's still a good 4" of water in the tank as the flapper is positioned that high off the tank bottom! What is the purpose of this design?

Easy and inexpensive assembly. It doesn't hurt anything, doesn't increase actual water use, and makes getting a good seal between valve and ceramic tank easier. (Typos fixed.)
